# Pass variable with set value to a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little span element which I CSSed the f*** out of so that it appears as a switch. It kind of like this:

```
<Span class="switchbody" value="on"><span class="switchcover">on</span></span>
```

I wanted to know, if I added an `onclick="editswitch()"` to the first span element, would it be possible if I passed a Variable containing a unique value so that the JavaScript function knows which switch I am talking about without me having to write a million functions doing exactly the same thing to different elements?

If it is possible, how would I do that

PS I have tried

```
<span onclick="getId = "switch one";">
```

If it is possible, no jquery or php, etc. Just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the object that fired the event. For example:

```js
function editswitch(me) {
  alert(me.id);
}
```

```html
<span id="span1" onclick="editswitch(this)">I'm the first span</span>
<br/>
<span id="span2" onclick="editswitch(this)">I'm the second span</span>
```

Comment: Nice, was hoping for something like that.

Comment: So, did I get This right, It takes the entire element, and how would I get It's ID?

Comment: Yes, `this` gives you the entire object. Use the `id` property of the object to get the value you want. See my updated answer.